# How to merge the nested json or dictionary values present in list

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
[{"2018":
    {"8":{ "total_queries_count": 4,
        "queries_without_teachers": 3,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["landmark", "232843"],
        "user_dislike": 0
        },
    "9":{ "total_queries_count": 1021,
     "queries_without_teachers": 0,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1021,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["1465146", "itassistant", "rame", "12345"],
        "user_dislike": 0},
    "10": {"total_queries_count": 352,
     "queries_without_teachers": 1,
         "non_teacher_queries": 351,
         "total_dislike": 0,
         "unique_users": ["1465146", "12345", "232843"],
         "user_dislike": 0
         }},
{"2018":
    {"8":{ "total_queries_count": 4,
        "queries_without_teachers": 3,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["landmark", "232843"],
        "user_dislike": 0
        },
    "9":{ "total_queries_count": 1021,
     "queries_without_teachers": 0,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1021,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["sddff", "1234", "12345"],
        "user_dislike": 0},
    "10": {"total_queries_count": 352,
     "queries_without_teachers": 1,
         "non_teacher_queries": 351,
         "total_dislike": 0,
         "unique_users": ["1465146", "777" ],
         "user_dislike": 0
         }}]
```

How to merge the nested json or dictionary values which are shown above? The resultant should be aggregated or Summed values. The **key** `"unique_users":[]` contains list of values which need to added in one common list and then counting the unique values present in the list. Here above two dictionary having the same **key** as "2018" followed by other key value pairs. The output should be like the following **such that each value can be extracted.** Example if i want the values of total_queries_count of 2018 year and month of 8, it should retrun 8.

```
[{"2018":
    {"8":{ "total_queries_count": 8,
        "queries_without_teachers": 6,
        "non_teacher_queries": 2,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": 2
        "user_dislike": 0
        },
    "9":{ "total_queries_count": 2042,
     "queries_without_teachers": 0,
        "non_teacher_queries": 2042,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": 6,
        "user_dislike": 0},
    "10": {"total_queries_count": 704,
     "queries_without_teachers": 2,
         "non_teacher_queries": 702,
         "total_dislike": 0,
         "unique_users": 4,
         "user_dislike": 0
         }}]
```

I tried following code but not able to do for multiple key value pairs.

```
from operator import itemgetter 
# Initialising list of dictionary 
ini_dict = [{'a':5, 'b':10, 'c':90}, {'a':45, 'b':78},  {'a':90, 'c':10}] 
# printing initial dictionary 
print ("initial dictionary", str(ini_dict)) 
# sum the values with same keys 
result = {} 
for d in ini_dict: 
    for k in d.keys(): 
        result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + d[k] 
print("resultant dictionary : ", str(result))
```

Comment: Your original list of dictionaries is malformed. Is it supposed to be a list of dictionaries with identical keys, but different values or a dictionary with multiple same top-level keys? Your very first curly brace has no matching closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new result dictionary that contains the first dictionary of the main dictionary and iterating over the second dictionary until the end and aggregating the similar data from the nested dictionaries

```
main_ls = [{"2018":
    {"8":{ "total_queries_count": 4,
        "queries_without_teachers": 3,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["landmark", "232843"],
        "user_dislike": 0
        },
    "9":{ "total_queries_count": 1021,
     "queries_without_teachers": 0,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1021,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["1465146", "itassistant", "rame", "12345"],
        "user_dislike": 0},
    "10": {"total_queries_count": 352,
     "queries_without_teachers": 1,
         "non_teacher_queries": 351,
         "total_dislike": 0,
         "unique_users": ["1465146", "12345", "232843"],
         "user_dislike": 0
         }}},
{"2018":
    {"8":{ "total_queries_count": 4,
        "queries_without_teachers": 3,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["landmark", "232843"],
        "user_dislike": 0
        },
    "9":{ "total_queries_count": 1021,
     "queries_without_teachers": 0,
        "non_teacher_queries": 1021,
        "total_dislike": 0,
        "unique_users": ["sddff", "1234", "12345"],
        "user_dislike": 0},
    "10": {"total_queries_count": 352,
     "queries_without_teachers": 1,
         "non_teacher_queries": 351,
         "total_dislike": 0,
         "unique_users": ["1465146", "777" ],
         "user_dislike": 0
         }}}]
res_dict = main_ls[0]
for obj in main_ls[1:]:
    for key, val in obj.items():
        for k, v in val.items():
            for res_key in res_dict[key][k].keys():
                current = obj[key][k][res_key]
                if isinstance(current, int):
                    res_dict[key][k][res_key] += current
                elif isinstance(current, list):
                    c = res_dict[key][k][res_key]
                    res_dict[key][k][res_key] =  len(c) + len(current) if isinstance(c, list) else c + len(current)
print([res_dict])
```

Output

```
[{'2018': {'8': {'total_queries_count': 8, 'queries_without_teachers': 6,
'non_teacher_queries': 2, 'total_dislike': 0, 'unique_users': 4, 'user_dislike': 0}, '9': 
{'total_queries_count': 2042, 'queries_without_teachers': 0, 'non_teacher_queries': 2042, 
'total_dislike': 0, 'unique_users': 7, 'user_dislike': 0}, '10': {'total_queries_count': 
704, 'queries_without_teachers': 2, 'non_teacher_queries': 702, 'total_dislike': 0, 
'unique_users': 5, 'user_dislike': 0}}}]
```

Comment: The resultant  should be for 'unique_users' = 2, because it is the count of unique element present in the megred list.For eg. ["landmark", "232843","landmark", "232843"]  'landmark' &'232843' present twice in the list. but the count should be 2.

Comment: If in res_dict contains list of dictionary with '2019', '2020', '2018' etc as key then i am getting Key Error: '2019', @Leo Arad could you please tell how to merge if there are other keys also present in the list. For example as you did for '2018' which is correct, just make one nested dictionary '2019' as key. Therefore the output should be of '2018' having merged values and '2019'  as it is dictionary in list.

Comment: I've edited the code to support multiple years for the unique use list I've aggregated all the unique users to the list this code wouldn't be able to count unique users when aggregating the values.

Comment: if you replace one key from '2018' to '2019'. Then in output will not merge because they are not having the same key. Your code is able to merge only for '2018'. I copy pasted your code and tried with other key eg. '2019' it's giving Key Error: '2019'.If we are keeping different keys in the list then output should be without merge. Is there any way i can communicate with you?

Comment: I tried your code for multiple years in the list. But its giving Key Error :'2019'. Your code should be such that if there are multiple years in which '2018' is two times, then output should merged dictionary values for '2018' and rest of the key values as it is.